# Changing several names at once in column in data.frame in R

Tags: r

I want to change the names of the column `PitchAccent` in my `data` data.frame that are not `no` into `yes` using something like:

```
data$Pitch<-gsub(!("no"), "yes", data$PitchAccent)
```

Saving it into a new column.

Since I have about 10 different names that I want to change into `yes` it would be annoying to run `data$Pitch<-gsub("H*L","yes",data$PitchAccent)` that many times.

Is there a better way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

In `PitchAccent` column we have:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide enough info to make this example reproducible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I don't really know if you have many different words alongside `"yes"` so to make sense of using `gsub` or something like it.

If you only have single words in your `PitchAccent` column

```
yes_words = c(... words you want to change into "yes" ...)
data$Pitch <- data$PitchAccent
data$Pitch[data$Pitch %in% yes_words] <- "yes"
```

If you have to detect those words

```
library(stringr)
yes_ind = str_detect(data$PitchAccent, c("strings that identify which elements you need to change"))

data$Pitch <- data$PitchAccent
data$Pitch[yes_ind] <- "yes"
```

Comment: I had `PitchAccent` column as factors. So I changed them into characters and now it should work :) Thank you!

Comment: But what if I have a hundred words for `yes_words`? I was wondering if it's possible to do something like "all the words that are NOT `no`" without enumerating them.

Comment: Then just run `data$Pitch[data$Pitch != "no"] <- "yes"`

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks! :)